# TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.state.list.map')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

so I'm trying to push a variable onto an array called list from my state. But it is throwing off this error saying that undefined is not a function. However, when I switch push to concat, it works. But I want to use push because it is faster. How do I fix this problem?

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("one").then((value) => {
    if (value === "true"){
      this.setState({
        list: this.state.list.push({
          name: 'Butter',
          checkbox: 1,
        })
      })
    }
    else {
      this.setState({
        unavailable: this.state.unavailable.push(
          "butter"
        )
      })
    }
});
```

My list is declared like this

```
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      unavailable: [],
      list: [] 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where is `this.state.list.map`?? Post the *exact* error.

Comment: Don't use `push()`, it mutates the array it's called from. You shouldn't ever directly mutate the state in React.

Comment: oh i added a bit from this.state.list.map sorry

Comment: the thing is my application is a bit slow right now, and i want to try to speed it up with push if i can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.push()` does not return the array, it returns the array length. Thus, the list changes from an array to a number. It also mutates the array directly.

As others have stated, it'd be better to do something like this:

```
this.setState({
    list: [
        ...this.state.list,
        { name: 'Butter', checkbox: 1 }
    ]
})
```

This way the state is not mutated directly from using `push()`.

Thought I'd also explain what is happening for those interested. Instead of mutating, or changing, the `ths.state.list` array directly, we're copying the current array to a new array and also appending the new item at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you have a problem with pushing data into React state array

You need to push values to array like below in React. You are doing incorrect way also you are never recommended to mutate any state in React. Below is the recommended way to mutate React state array

```
  this.setState(prevState => {
    list: [...prevState.list, {
      name: 'Butter',
      checkbox: 1,
    }]
  })
```

Like change this to

```
   this.setState( prevState => {
    unavailable: [...prevState.unavailable, "butter"]
  })
```

Also keep in mind that you are not recommended to do setState in loop. When you want to modify the state value from the loop then declare a local variable and use that for assigning values from loop and finally do setState outside the loop otherwise you will get infinite warnings

Comment: thanks heaps, blacky wolf answered first, but thanks so much anyways

Comment: Ok NP. This is different and recommended way of dealing with arrays in React.